# How can I stop outputting text, when a condition is met?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this code to tell me if a bitcoin is below to a certain value, but the problem is that when i run this code, It keeps spamming either conditions "okay" or "not okay". so I'm wondering how can i stop this process, so that when it's below target, it'll just say not okay and stop outputting until price of bitcoin rises.

```
target = 9440
while True:
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    price = float(data.get('bpi').get('USD').get('rate').replace(",", ""))
    if price <= target:
        print("Not okay\n")
    else:
        print("Okay\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two possible states, "okay" and "not okay" you need to use a variable that keeps the state of previous query. If `previousState` was the same as the current state do nothing, if they're different print the text.
Here's some code that should solve the problem:

```
target = 9440
previousState = false; // use true as "okay" and false as "not okay"
while True:
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    price = float(data.get('bpi').get('USD').get('rate').replace(",", ""))
    if ((price <= target) and (previousState == true)):
        print("Not okay\n")
    elif((price >= target) and (previousState == false)):
        print("Okay\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will print only a when there's change of value:

```
import urllib
from time import sleep

def generate(target):
    previous = float('nan')

    while True:
        sleep(1)    # sleep 1second to not spam the API

        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json") as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            value = float(data['bpi']['USD']['rate'].replace(",", ""))

            if previous == value:
                continue

            if value <= target:
                yield 'Okay', value
            else:
                yield 'Not Okay', value

            previous = value


target = 9440
for value in generate(target):
    print(value)
```

Prints:

```
('Not Okay', 9550.425)
('Not Okay', 9550.325)
('Not Okay', 9554.63)
('Not Okay', 9554.5233)

... and so on.
```

---

If you want to get information only when there's change between `Okay` and `Not Okay`, you can do this:

```
import urllib
from time import sleep

def generate(target):
    previous = float('nan')
    previous_state = ''

    while True:
        sleep(1)    # sleep 1second to not spam the API

        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json") as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            value = float(data['bpi']['USD']['rate'].replace(",", ""))

            if previous == value:
                continue

            if value <= target and previous_state != 'Okay':
                previous_state = 'Okay'
                yield previous_state, value
            elif value > target and previous_state != 'Not Okay':
                previous_state = 'Not Okay'
                yield previous_state, value

            previous = value


target = 9553.1
for value in generate(target):
    print(value)
```

Prints:

```
('Not Okay', 9553.1017)
('Okay', 9552.9817)
('Not Okay', 9556.5983)

... and so on.
```